# Inconsistent behaviour of package private access level

Tags: java

I know that package-private (default) modifier is supposed to hide a method (or member) for every class, except those in the same package. However, I discovered some issues with this access-level.

Consider the following code:

```
// pack1/MyBaseClass.java
package pack1;

public class MyBaseClass {
    /* package private */ void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyBaseClass.someMethod");
    }
}


// pack1/MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage.java
package pack1;

import pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage;

public class MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage extends MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage {
    @Override
    /* package private */ void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage.someMethod");
        // super.someMethod();  // can't compile
    }
}


//pack2/MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage.java
package pack2;

import pack1.MyBaseClass;

public class MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage extends MyBaseClass {
    // @Override // can't do this (compile error)
    /* package private */ void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage.someMethod");
    }
}
```

So basically there is a base class in package pack1 with a package-private method (MyBaseClass). Another class in pack2 (MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage) extends MyBaseClass, and it cannot override the package-private method (so far ok: package-private methods are accessible only within the same package).
However, another class in pack1 extends pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage, and this time it can override its package-private method (but it cannot call `super.someMethod()`).

Another strange thing is that someMethod behaves polymorphically for `pack1.MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage` but not `pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage`. The below code should make it clear what I mean:

```
package pack1;

import pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyBaseClass bc = new MyBaseClass();
        bc.someMethod();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

        MyBaseClass otherpack = new MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage();
        otherpack.someMethod();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

        MyBaseClass samepack = new MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage();
        samepack.someMethod();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

    }

}
```

Output:

```
MyBaseClass.someMethod
-------------------------------------------------
MyBaseClass.someMethod
-------------------------------------------------
MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage.someMethod
-------------------------------------------------
```

Questions related to these behaviours:

```
1. How come that pack1.MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage is allowed to override the (package-private) method of pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage?
2. In spite of this, why is it not possible to call super.someMethod() from pack1.MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage?
3. Why is the class in the same package (pack1) behaving polymorphically and the one in the other package (pack2) not?
```

PS1.: I know that I should post one question at a time on SO, but I feel that the three issues somehow must have the same root cause. (I suspect that in reality pack1.MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage.someFunction is overriding pack1.MyBaseClass.someFunction and not pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage.someFunction. But this would still not explain the second question, and besides I could not confirm it.)

PS2.: I don't have any real usecase for this scenario. I'm just playing around with the corner cases (in preparation for the OCA exam).

Comment: Have you tried overriding someMethod in pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage with the `public` modifier?

Comment: @broncoAbierto: I don't get your suggestion. If I would do that, how would it help me in understanding the behaviour of package-private (default) access level. (Which is the purpose of the question.)

Comment: My guess is that you can't override because by declaring its visibility to pack2-package private you are restricting its accessibility.

Comment: @RKC: thanks for your improvements. I don't understand the last one, though: why did you put my questions into code?

Comment: @broncoAbierto: Ok, but then why does it let me put the override annotation on in spite of this? (See first question.)

Comment: What's the error message? You can always put the Override annotation. It will enforce certain requirements on the following declaration, but it will never (I think) cause an error in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) What you are overriding here is not MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage#someMethod, but MyBaseClass#someMethod(). The first one is skipped over due to package privacy, and the compiler correctly resolves the overridden level to MyBaseClass instead, since your child class is in the same package as it.

Notice that this holds under the assumption that we remove the @Override annotation from the second class in the hierarchy - otherwise your code does not even compile.

The interesting follow-up question here would be why the annotation system still throws an error while the code compiles just fine in this case.

2) Because super resolves to the immediate superclass, whose method you in this case have no access to.

3) Edit: as pointed out in BroncoAbiertos answer, this is simply because this is the only place where the method is actually overridden. In fact you can only actually get this to compile by removing the @Override annotation from the second class as indicated in answer 1 above, otherwise your code will not compile.

Comment: Regarding the first answer, I think it compiles because it simply does not override the parent method. If you add the override annotation, however, you're telling the compiler to make sure that you are overriding something, which is why it does not compile.

Comment: True, but I was thinking about the annotation in the third class in the hierarchy. If you leave that annotation only, and remove the second one, the code compiles, but the annotation processor will STILL complain about an error.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for clarifying. Both answers are correct in my opinion, but unluckily I can accept only one...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't override someMethod in pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage because you're declaring it package private to pack2. That is, you are eliminating access from pack1, thus restricting its visibility, which is illegal when overriding a method. When you override it from pack1.MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage the visibility stays the same, which is legal.
2. You can't call super.someMethod() because you are trying to access pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage.someMethod(), but can't access pack2.MyDerivedClassInAnotherPackage methods from pack1.
3. Well, the method is only overridden in pack1.MyDerivedClassFromOtherPackage, so that's not strange.